# Where should I create Kafka Consumers in an Akka actor?

Tags: java, akka, apache-kafka

I'm trying to create a Akka-Kafka consumer. 
Similar to documentation of Kafka's consumer group ([Consumer Group Example doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example)), I create an Actor *KafkaConsumerGroupMaster* and an actor *KafkaConsumer*.

The *KafkaConsumerGroupMaster* actor will recieve a zookeeper, a topic and the amount of streams to create and listen to.

Where is it better to create the *KafkaConsumer* actors?
My thoughts were: (1) in a **preStart()** in the group master actor. (2) as a message of creation in the **onRecieve()** of the group master.

Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 4):

If you create child actors (or do any of the initialization) while handling some `Init` message, you will have to make sure to send that message again, when your actor is restarted because of en error, for example.

This does not have to be taken into account if you do the initialization in the `preStart()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I created the consumer thread in onStart overridden method of Global class (extended from play.GlobalSettings). Also, I did not use the Java threadservice executor. Instead I created a KafkaRunnable and directly executed it with a Akka.system().dispatcher().execute() call.

KafkaRunnable.java

```
package infrastructure.kafka;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import play.Logger;
import controllers.OrderController;
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator;
import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;
import kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata;
public class KafkaRunnable implements Runnable {
  private KafkaStream<byte[],byte[]> m_stream;
  private int m_threadNumber;
  public KafkaRunnable(KafkaStream<byte[],byte[]> a_stream, int a_threadNumber) {
    m_threadNumber = a_threadNumber;
    m_stream = a_stream;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Logger.info("Starting Thread: " + m_threadNumber);
    ConsumerIterator<byte[],byte[]> it = m_stream.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()){
        MessageAndMetadata<byte[],byte[]> msg=it.next();
        String orderId=new String(msg.key(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String uri=new String(msg.message(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        try{
            Logger.info("Thread " + m_threadNumber + ": OrderId:" + orderId+";URI:"+uri);
            OrderController.notifyOrder(orderId, uri);
        }catch (Throwable ex){
            Logger.error("Error in notify order. ", ex);
        }

    }
    Logger.info("Shutting down Thread: " + m_threadNumber);
  }
}
```

KafkaConsumer.java

```
package infrastructure.kafka;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import play.Logger;
import play.libs.Akka;
import kafka.consumer.Consumer;
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;
import kafka.javaapi.consumer.ConsumerConnector;


public class KafkaConsumer{
    public static ConsumerConfig createConsumerConfig() {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("zookeeper.connect",     play.Play.application().configuration().getString("zookeeper.connect"));
        props.put("group.id", "notifyOrder");
        props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "400");
        props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "200");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");

        return new ConsumerConfig(props);
    }   
    private static ConsumerConnector consumer;
    public static void start(int noOfThreads){
        final String topic="neworder";

        //Create Consumer config
        ConsumerConfig cfg=KafkaConsumer.createConsumerConfig();
        consumer=Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(cfg);
        Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(noOfThreads));
        Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
        List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);
        int threadNumber = 0;
        for (final KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream : streams) {
            Akka.system().dispatcher().execute(new KafkaRunnable(stream, threadNumber));
            threadNumber++;
        }       
    }
    public static void shutDown(){
        if (consumer!=null){
            Logger.info("Initiating Kafka Consumer shutdown");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }

            consumer.shutdown();
            Logger.info("Kafka Consumer shutdown complete");
        }
    }
}
```